# I need my paragraph to display when clicking on my input boxes. How is my p array not cycling through my paragraph variables?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to loop through my p array to find each paragraph variable so that I can change the opacity of my HTML.

```
var p1 = document.querySelector(".p1");
var p2 = document.querySelector(".p2");
var p3 = document.querySelector(".p3");

var p = [1,2,3];
function visible() {
    for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        p[i].style.opacity = 1;
    }

 }
```

The result I am looking for is when I click an input text box I want my paragraph to show. The visible function is an html onclick function.

Comment: So when you click a text box you want p1, p2, and p3 to all be shown?

Comment: There is an individual text box for each (p1, p2, p3). When I click on the text box that corresponds to p1 or the others, I want that text to be visible etc. So I am cycling through the p array to find p1, p2, and p3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean

```
var p = [p1,p2,p3];
```

not

```
var p = [1,2,3];
```

edited

You can add a parameter inside your html.

```html
<input type="number" onclick="displayParagraph('.p1')">
<input type="number" onclick="displayParagraph('.p2')">
<input type="number" onclick="displayParagraph('.p3')">
```

```
function displayParagraph(paragraphClass){
var p = document.querySelector(paragraphClass);
p.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

Comment: I just tried it. That displays all my paragraphs when I click on one text box. I need var i to equal 1, 2, or 3. In that sense, wouldnt it make the code: p[1, 2, 3].style.opacity = 1;

Comment: Ok now i get it. You have three input fields with onclick function i guess.

Comment: Thats exactly it! I keep getting an error though. Not really sure why.

Comment: Thank you, that was it! I am still trying to get used to parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let p1 = document.getElementsByClassName("p1");
let p2 = document.getElementsByClassName("p2");
let p3 = document.getElementsByClassName("p3");
let pArray = [];
pArray.push(p1,p2,p3);


setTimeout(()=>{
    pArray.map((x)=>{
        x[0].style.opacity =1
    })
},0);
```

Now we have to use the setTimeout function, because the p1 and p2 and p3 are Still unknown to the DOM in your javascript file. if you will use JQuery for instance and put your code in the $( document ).ready() {} function it will be known.